# excel VBA How to insert the same piece of text in more than 1 place in the word document?

Tags: excel, vba

I have built an excel VBA that

- opens a word template
- get 10 different text/value from my excel sheet (cells)
- insert those text/value into the word document (from word template) at the 10 bookmarks spot. code: `.Bookmarks("bookmarkname").Range.Text = text` that I want

All these are working well the problem comes when one of the bookmarks called clientNumber, is repeated. It appears once in page1 of the doc and in the headers from page 2 onwards.

I cant have 2 bookmarks of the same name in the document.
I googled and tried to make the header's `clientNumber` cross-reference to the 1st `clientNumber` bookmark but VBA only inserts text at the bookmark, not at cross-ref.

So, the main qn is how to insert that same piece of text (eg. `12345678`) at more than 1 positions in a word document?

I saw this link: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/41654-how-find-if-word-part-cross-reference.html

but I dont rly understand how it works

Comment: You can make two bookmarks, one named `clientNumber1` and the other `clientNumber2` and insert the same text in both bookmarks